# Bind href inside interpolation in angular

Tags: html, angular

Need to bind the redirecting link inside the string interpolation response.

- I am displaying the API response value inside the interpolation binding.
- For example my response is, "**This site is not working. please contact google for more information**", here i need to give the redirecting link for "**contact google**" and it should redirect to the "**www.google.com**" page.
- Assume "**servicerequest.errormessage**" is my response i am getting from node.

Service Response :

**servicerequest.errormessage** == **"This site is not working. please contact google for more information"**

Then my html code like,

html bind :

{{**servicerequest.errormessage**}}

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hello-world-gnorrk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html)

here first i need to split the data. and i need to add the redirect link only for "Contact Google". How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to the following:

- Include hyperlinks in the strings which you display in case of an error-response.

I think you can achieve this by including html-tags in your string and then using `[innerHTML]`:

First the **TS-File:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  htmlErrorMessage = 'This site is not working. <a href="https://www.google.ch">please contact google</a<> for more information';
}
```

Then the **HTML-Part**:

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlErrorMessage"></div>
```